# Rename image before wordpress upload it

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have a blog in wordpress where I upload multiples images per post, but It causing me and issue.

If the filename have whitespaces, special chars or something like that, It broke the upload. Also this issue is overwriting me the files with the same name. For example: First I upload a photo whose filename is "car.png". Then i upload other image with the same name, "car.png", It show me the first photo that I was uploaded.

I want to rename the files previuosly the upload with a date hash (year, month, day, hour, minute and second when It was uploaded).

How can I do this with a hook or a codex function?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function I always add to my WP Themes Functions File:

```
function sanitize_file_uploads( $file ){
    $file['name'] = sanitize_file_name($file['name']);
    $file['name'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]/", "", $file['name']);
    $file['name'] = strtolower($file['name']);
    add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'remove_accents');

    return $file;
}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'sanitize_file_uploads');
```

Trims is, remove special unaccepted characters, converts name to lowercase, and remove accents. Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: @JackBlack That will run the file name through a [`remove_accents` WordPress Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents) turning `Hoy será un gran día` to `Hoy sera un gran dia`. File systems sometimes have trouble with accents in filenames.

Comment: is here any way to get the attachment_id or parent id in here?